# Search/Indexing in windows 10 broken

Tags: windows, windows-10, services, windows-search

I recently tried moving the location of windows's Index files from my C (SSD) drive to another regular drive with more space...

I went to the Advanced Options under Indexing Options and put the 'new' path there...

Everything seem to run well for a day or 2.
But now search has stopped working. Even typing the name of a program into the start menu brings up nothing.

I checked the indexing options and now it shows me this :

[image]

The advanced options show me this :

[image]

I checked the services.msc and it shows that windows search is stopped. If I start the service , nothing happens.

I can't put a new location into the advanced indexing options as the 'select new' button is disabled, as are the 2 text fields...

The rebuild button does nothing either.

Running the troubleshooter tells me that the indexing service is turned off and should be turned on.

I tried checking the registry... under the directory `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows` Search I see that 'data directory' is set to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\` (the default), as is 'defaultDataDirectory'.

So, any suggestions how I can restore windows indexing, preferably with the indexing files not on my C drive.

thanks!

Comment: "indexing not running" lloks like the service is stopped. Run services.msc and start the WindowsSearch service.

Comment: i did mention i tried turning the service on :)... even after several restarts the service is marked as stopped, and nothing happens if i try and start it...

Answer (score 0):

and fixed the problem :)

the solution was found here :[Upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 10, Window Search service no longer starts](https://superuser.com/questions/964861/upgraded-windows-7-to-windows-10-window-search-service-no-longer-starts?rq=1)

the registry entry for the indexing location wasn't the ones i posted in my question , but can be found here : `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\Gathering Manager\DefaultApplicationsPath`

once i changed that to a correct path and rebooted everything went back to normal.